# How do I scrape data from multiple <br> tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How do I scrape data from the following to get the Company, Name, address, city state, zip, Phone, email, website as different columns? from
 https://directory.justice.org/SearchResult.asp?access=public&firstmiddlename=&middlename=&lastname=&maidenname=&firmname=&city=&provstateid=&zip=&countryid=&keyword=&areaofpractice=&areaofpractice2=Personal+Injury&sectiontype=&memtype=&sb=&gender=Any

I want to split the details of the attorneys under various br tags to be separate entities i am stuck after finding the attorneys details how do i assign each br tag to a value like name? address etc?

```
    import pandas as pd
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
   import requests
  import re
     data =[]
     res=requests.get("https://directory.justice.org/SearchResult.asp?access=public&firstmiddlename=&middlename=&lastname=&maidenname=&firmname=&city=&provstateid=&zip=&countryid=&keyword=&areaofpractice=&areaofpractice2=Personal+Injury&sectiontype=&memtype=&sb=&gender=Any")
     soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
     lawyers=soup.findAll('div',{'style':'float:left'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString
import pandas as pd
import requests


res=requests.get("https://directory.justice.org/SearchResult.asp?access=public&firstmiddlename=&middlename=&lastname=&maidenname=&firmname=&city=&provstateid=&zip=&countryid=&keyword=&areaofpractice=&areaofpractice2=Personal+Injury&sectiontype=&memtype=&sb=&gender=Any")

soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
lawyers=soup.findAll('div',{'style':'float:left'})
roster = []
for law in lawyers:
    data = []
    for item in law:
        if isinstance(item, Tag) and len(item.text.strip())>0:
            data.append(item.text.strip())
        if isinstance(item, NavigableString):
            data.append(item.strip())
    roster.append(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(roster) 
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

### I have also found an alternative way to work this out:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
 import requests
 import re
data=[]
 res=requests.get("https://directory.justice.org/SearchResult.asp?access=public&firstmiddlename=&middlename=&lastname=&maidenname=&firmname=&city=&provstateid=&zip=&countryid=&keyword=&areaofpractice=&areaofpractice2=Personal+Injury&sectiontype=&memtype=&sb=&gender=Any")
 soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
 lawyer=soup.findAll('div',{'style':'float:left'})
for item in lawyer:
    lawyer_company=(item.contents[0].text)
    lawyer_name=(item.contents[2])
    lawyer_address=(item.contents[4])
    lawyer_city=(item.contents[6])
    lawyer_state=(item.contents[6])
    lawyer_zip=(item.contents[6])

    lawyer_phone=(item.contents[8])
    lawyer_email=(item.contents[11])
    if isinstance(lawyer_email, Tag):
              lawyer_email=lawyer_email.text.strip()
    lawyer_website=(item.contents[13])
    if isinstance(lawyer_website, Tag):
              lawyer_website=lawyer_website.text.strip()
    full_dict={'Company':lawyer_company, 'Name':lawyer_name,'Address':lawyer_address,'City':lawyer_city,'State':lawyer_state,'Zip':lawyer_zip,'Phone':lawyer_phone,'Email':lawyer_phone,'Website':lawyer_website}
    data.append(full_dict)


 df=pd.DataFrame(data)
 print(df)
```